# Does any one has a python code to convert all mp4 files in folder to mp3?

Tags: python

For instance, i have five .mp4 in a folder. How do i loop and convert them to .mp3 and output them in a different folder?

Thanks

I have tried this but it is not working.

```
**import moviepy.editor as mp
import re
tgt_folder = "D:/Music/video"
 
for file in [n for n in os.listdir(tgt_folder) if re.search('mp4',n)]:
    full_path = os.path.join(tgt_folder, file)
    output_path = os.path.join(tgt_folder, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.mp3')
    clip = mp.AudioFileClip(full_path).subclip(10,) # disable if do not want any clipping
    clip.write_audiofile('D:/Music/mp3')**
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using ffmpeg and python subprocces

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i video.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn music.mp3"])
```